# PHP transform array in comma seperated string

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seemn to make this work could someone help identify what is incorrect:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT accounts_client_email.client_email FROM accounts_client_email WHERE accounts_client_email.accounts_client_id = 1", $con);

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
$new_array[] = $row; // Inside while loop
}

$tags = implode(', ', array($new_array));

echo $tags;
```

Comment: You are collecting `$row`s, not the single result column. Access the desired array field.

Comment: as mario said `$new_array[] = $row['client_email'];`

Comment: besides What @Dale said,  $tags = implode(', ', $new_array);

Comment: I'm trying to turn a query result into a comma seperated string

Answer (score 1):

You aren't adding correctly to the array, it should be:

```
$new_array[] = $row['client_email'];
```

And you are encapsulating the array into another array unnecessarily;

use:

```
$tags = implode(', ', $new_array);
```

Or `echo $tags;` will just output "Array"

Comment: So my results come out like :
'xyz@gmail.com','abc@gmail.com'

Comment: OK worked it out :
    $new_array[] = "'".$row['client_email']."'";

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use scope with your column name to populate in your array

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result))
{
    $new_array[] = $row['client_email']; // Inside while loop
}
```

I would like to also to remember you that `mysql_*` functions are officially deprecated and no longer maintained so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for new projects.

Comment: @user1479981 try to use $tags = implode(', ', $new_array);

Answer (score 1):

You need to use brackets

```
$new_array[] = $row[]; // Inside while loop
```

If this doesnt work, use

```
 $new_array[] = $row['client_email']; // Inside while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

use for loop

```
$array_to_string="";
for($i=0;$i<=count($result_array)-1;$i++)
{
    if($i != count($result_array)-1)
    {
        $array_to_string .= $result_array[$i].",";
    }else
    {
        $array_to_string .= $result_array[$i];
    }
}
echo $array_to_string; // you get the string as a commoa seperated values which is available in the array
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a comma separated string, not an array, you can do it like this:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result))
{
    if(empty($tags)
        $tags = $row['client_email'];
    else
        $tags .= ', '.$row['client_email'];
}
echo $tags; //will display comma separated string - no arrays needed
```